# React app web app gives 404 error and Uncaught in Promise Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So we have an app with different modules, React on the front end, Java on the back end. All the modules work the same way. It has a dropdown that loads a list of names. All of them work, but one, which started giving this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
app.min.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Not Found
    at d (app.min.js:5)
```

The weird thing is that there has been no changes to this app, nor the code, nor the DB, in 5 months. It has been very consistent, so why would it show such an error out of nowhere, with no changes. I can add code, but I'm not sure if the code is the issue since there were no changes in months?

Comment: It sounds like the server is returning a 404.  Check the request being made, check the server-side code, etc.  There's nothing from the information provided that would tell us anything else.

Comment: But the code hasn't changed in months. What should I make of that ?

Comment: What you should make of it is that the server is returning a 404 for a particular request.  Essentially you're approaching this the wrong way.  Instead of insisting reasons why you think there *shouldn't* be a problem, investigate the problem itself.  You might find that something did change, either on the client or on the server or perhaps in the routing between the two, or that there's some other issue outside of the application code.  But simply insisting that everything should work isn't going to make it work, nor does it present an answerable question about the problem.